# How to find xpath of this button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVDHr.png)

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium css-7l669b" tabindex="0" type="button">Add New Profile<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f""style=""></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture seems that this element has unique `id` attribute, so I'd suggest to try this XPath:

```java
"//button[@id='AddNewProfile']"
```

Selenium command could be like this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='AddNewProfile']"));
```

Comment: Sorry image was wrong

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: need a credentials to log in

Comment: Thanks, but when I insert these credentials and click login button - signin button becomes gryed out but I was not logged in

Comment: if you have not logged in you can try signup process and then sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Select the element from the inspect tools by right click. Click on copy and then click on copy Xpath as highlighted in picture below.
[image]

Comment: I have also use this trick but it's not work.

Comment: Try copying full XPath.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been more helpful if the entire HTML document was available. But I suggest you look to see if the class value of the button element is stable and do either `//button[@class='<CLASS VALUE>']` or  `//button[contains(@class,'<ADD PART OF THE CLASS VALUE HERE>')]`